# Is it possible to deselect a ttk.Radiobutton?

Tags: python, tkinter

These are the `ttk.radiobuttons` I am using:

```
    def radioButtonGen(self):
        self.var = tk.IntVar()
        self.arithButton = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text = "Arithmetic Series", variable = self.var, value = 1, command = lambda: self.buttons.seqChoice("arithmetic"))
        self.geomButton = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text = "Geometric Series", variable = self.var, value = 2, command = lambda: self.buttons.seqChoice("geometric"))
```

I have attempted to deselect them with deselect() but it only works for tk.radiobuttons, which don't look as good and the method still leaves them with a dash.
I want to deselect them so they are not highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the associated tkinter variable to deselect them:

```py
self.var.set(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that was a ting